# How to use Hugo Icons Modules ( and fix can't evaluate field vendors in type string )

Tags: hugo

The [Hugo Icons Modules](https://hugomods.com/en/docs/icons/) shows the following example

```html
{{ $context := dict
  "vendor" "bootstrap"
  "name" "house"
}}

{{ partial "icons/icon" $context }}
```

When I add this to my partial `layouts/partials/header.html` Hugo fails to start with message

> onknows@io3:~/git/gitlab/c2/website$ hugo server
> Start building sites …
> hugo v0.111.3-5d4eb5154e1fed125ca8e9b5a0315c4180dab192+extended linux/amd64 BuildDate=2023-03-12T11:40:50Z VendorInfo=snap:0.111.3
> ERROR 2023/05/04 07:07:01 render of "section" failed: "/home/onknows/git/gitlab/c2/website/layouts/_default/baseof.html:25:7": execute of template failed: template: community/list.html:25:7: executing "community/list.html" at <partialCached "header" .>: error calling partialCached: "/home/onknows/git/gitlab/c2/website/layouts/partials/header.html:10:13": execute of template failed: template: partials/header.html:10:13: executing "partials/header.html" at <partial "icons/icon" $context>: error calling partial: "/tmp/hugo_cache/modules/filecache/modules/pkg/mod/github.com/hugomods/icons@v0.6.0/layouts/partials/icons/icon.html:10:15": execute of template failed: template: partials/icons/icon.html:10:15: executing "partials/icons/icon.html" at : can't evaluate field vendors in type string

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 1):

Author here. The issue was caused by the confliction of other Hugo modules that `icons` parameters were overridden unexpectedly.

A known example is that if imported themes/modules forgot to ignore the Bootstrap's [config](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8fcfce1ebd988fd4e5ed2f51acaa5c49e6b301c9/hugo.yml#L67) which is useless for users, then the `icons` parameter *maybe* overridden as a string.

There are two ways to fix the issue.

1. Ignore the Bootstrap config on upstream themes/modules, for example, [Ignore Bootstrap config from Docsy dependencies](https://github.com/google/docsy/pull/1509). **It's recommended** that users won't have unnecessary configurations on their sites.
2. Move the `github.com/hugomods/icons` or relative `hugomods` modules to the top, according to the priority of Hugo modules (from top to bottom), the `icons` parameters won't be overridden by others.

```yaml
module:
  imports:
    - path: github.com/hugomods/icons
    - path: exmaple.com/me/theme
    - path: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [icons/icon partial](https://github.com/hugomods/icons/blob/main/layouts/partials/icons/icon.html) is checking if `$vendor` is contained into `site.Params.icons.vendors`

Your error is `can't evaluate field vendors in type string`, which indicates that you probably have an issue with the installation of the modules that are required. It can happen if you are working on a local server and that Hugo cannot properly import the modules.